# Eclipse Juno, Maven and Glassfish 4.1 Hotdeploy (partially works)

Tags: eclipse, maven, glassfish, eclipse-juno, glassfish-4.1

Mostly by chance (I guess), any `.xhtml` pages or `.java` files I edit (`.java` in my parent maven module) do get hot-deployed.
But, if I change a `.java` file in my main WebApp module then the whole application gets redeployed.

Is there a way to make my WebApp `.java` class to be hot-deployed?

---

I have the following setup:

- A Maven multi-module project, with my Webapp module and a core module
- Eclipse Juno
- Glassfish 4.1
- I have installed the Glassfish tools setup with:

  - Automatically publish when a resource changes
  - Publish interval at 5 secs
  - (unchecked) Preserve sessions across redployments
  - (checked) Use JAR archives for deployment